# UIView Orientation in UINavigationController in IOS6

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

I have a UINavigation base app in which I was supporting all orientations for some view controller but not for all using this code

> @interface UINavigationController (Autorotation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
  @end

  @implementation UINavigationController (Autorotation)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

> if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[MWPhotoBrowser
>   class]] || [self.visibleViewController
>   isKindOfClass:[ZoomPictureViewController class]]) {
>           return YES;
>       }
>       return  (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); 
>   } 
>   @end

It was working great but not working in IOS6. I have set all four orientations supported in my projects plist file.

Help if anyone has found some work around for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link for apple documentation Read it :)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

In ios 6 there are new methods for orientation use these methods in your navigation controller subclass

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]] ||[self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]]) {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```